# SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyHHmm") with only 3y

Tags: java, simpledateformat

My application was working with a `SimpleDateFormat` bug. There was specified only 3y rather than 4 but it was generating a correct output with 4 digits. I don't know why from yesterday it started generating 2 digits only. I mean '14' instead of '2014'. I solved the problem just correcting the wrong format but I'm still wondering why it changed behavior. Any ideas about it? Thanks

Comment: Any code about it?Thanks

Comment: atleast post your codes man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe due to JVM version? I mean, making a test with Java6, I got 4 digits date, instead with Java 7, I got 2 digits. Reading the documentation, seems there is no difference between two implementations.

Comment: Thank you! I just realised to have changed JVM from 6 to 7 recently. It should be the cause! I will investigate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Any number of `y` letters but `yy` will be interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. For example, `y`, `yyy` and `yyyy` will give `2014`, `yyyyy` will give `02014` as an output. Only `yy` will give `14` as an output.

I don't know what changed the behaviour of output but its probably that you've accidentally deleted one `y` letter from it :)